# How to only show headings in MS Word navigation pane

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a very large doc with headings and when using the navigation pane it also shows the first line of every normal (or non-heading) paragraph below the heading.
This beats the purpose of the navigation pane as I need to scroll several pages before finding and being able to jump to the heading in the text.

Is there a way to make the navigation pane ONLY show headings?

thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Navigation Pane *only* shows paragraphs that have an outline heading level. Period.

*That something else seems to be showing means that you have a non-heading paragraph with an outline level assigned.*

1. Navigate to such a paragraph by clicking on it in the Navigation
   pane.
2. Change it to the Normal style or Body Text or some other body-level paragraph style.

It should disappear from the Navigation Pane.

If you like, include a link to a sample document with the problem (a few pages only, please) and I will tell you exactly where the problem is. Here is [my article on the MS website](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258) telling how to do this.

*You can, also, right-click in the Navigation pane and temporarily change the number of levels displayed. This may help.*

Here is my article on [Headings that Do Not Appear in the Navigation Pane or a Table of Contents](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/headings-that-do-not-show-up-in-the-navigation/1d3bdc6d-218b-4b90-8e58-f1e0530f75bd) for the flip-side of the problem.

Here is my page on [Outlining in Microsoft Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/outlining.htm) for more context.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was that in the template somebody had indeed assigned an outline level to "normal". I did not know that was possible. Problem solved!

Comment: You are welcome.